# Does JavaScript have late binding (in the type sense)?

Tags: javascript

Late binding, when referring to types, means that a type is unknown until runtime.

Is JavaScript a late-bound language?

I presume it is because it has a small number of primitive types and everything else is an instance of Object, and the nature of a type is coerced at runtime.

```
var a = 1, b = 'a', c;

c = a + b; // c is a string, but this is only determined at runtime?
```

Comment: JS _only_ has runtime

Comment: @Alnitak so that is a "yes types are late-bound in JavaScript" then?

Answer (score 4):

That said, (referring to Nisk's answer) - you actually CAN emulate a late-binding in Javascript.

The code below basically explains the following

*Rather than binding a function with values which cannot be changed later - bind with a value that you **CAN** change later i.e. bind the function with an Object instead - because you can always alter the properties of an object after it has been defined.*

#### Early Binding using the `.bind` method

```
// Early Binding
var sum = function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
};

var x = 5, y = 6;
var sum5n6 = sum.bind(null, x, y);

x = 10;
y = 5;
console.log("with Early Binding -->", sum5n6());    // 11
```

#### Late Binding using the `.bind` method

```
var sum2 = function(p) {
  return p.x + p.y;
};

var x = 5, y = 6;
var n = {x: x, y: y};
var sumLate = sum2.bind(null, n);

// even though you have "bound" n to sumLate, you can still change
//  the properties of n
n.x = 10;
n.y = 5;
console.log("Late Binding -->", sumLate());  // 15
```

Answer (score -1):

Late-binding is not really for datatypes, that's type-inference. Javascript is a just-in-time (JIT) compiled, all the types are inferred at runtime.

Late-binding is more to do with Object-oriented languages, more specifically objects (polymorphism/inheritance etc), not basic types.

Hope that helps.

Comment: As I understand it, the term late binding can be applied to both dynamic dispatch (i.e. runtime method resolution) *and* type resolution. Based on your answer, it would appear JavaScript does exhibit late-binding of types.

Comment: Well the very reason I distinguished between type inference and late binding is because Late-binding is more to do with method resolution, javascript does not exhibit the typical v-table of methods or inheritance for one to use the term late-binding, instead it is a prototypical(object) language. Late-binding is mostly concerned at which point in time (just before it runs, for late-binding) the method resolutions happens for complex objects - which does not apply to javascript directly.